# Custom Regular Scale (pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scale, logarithm

I would like to know if some of you knew how to make an irregular custom scale on pyplot.

Here is my basic script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax= plt.subplots()
ax.set_yticks([0, 5, 27, 40])
```

I would like to have the same space on my y-axis between 0 and 5, and then, the same space between 5 and 27, and then the same between 27 and 40....

Somebody would have the solution?

I tried using logarithmic scale, but it doesn't fit to me, I would prefer a more customed scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your grid points and interpolate data onto those. Start with:

```
import numpy as np
x_ticks = np.array([0, 5, 27, 40])
x_reg = np.arange(len(x_ticks))
```

Now suppose your actual data is `y` defined at points `x`. You can convert the `x` values, and then plot:

```
x_plot = np.interp(x, x_ticks, x_reg)
plt.plot(x_plot, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to define an *ad hoc* normalizing class

```
In [27]: class normalize():
    ...:     def __init__(self, positions):
    ...:         self.positions = positions.sort() or positions
    ...:         self.outputs = np.arange(len(positions))/(len(positions)-1)
    ...:     def __call__(self, x):
    ...:         return np.interp(x, self.positions, self.outputs, np.nan, np.nan)
```

and be careful in the definition of the `y` spine (in the following, for the sake of the example, I'm going to plot *y = 20 (x+x²)*)

```
In [28]: positions = [0, 5, 27, 40]
    ...: f = normalize(positions)
    ...: lp = len(positions)
    ...:
    ...: fig, ax= plt.subplots()
    ...:
    ...: ax.set_ylim(-0.05, 1.05) # standard Matplotlib margins
    ...: ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,lp)/(lp-1))
    ...: ax.set_yticklabels((repr(p) for p in positions))
    ...:
    ...: x = np.linspace(0, 1, 101) ; y=20*x*(1+x)
    ...:
    ...: plt.plot(x, f(y))
    ...: plt.grid()
```

[image: my plot]